# LibGDX initialize Drawable

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

This is a Question for those who are familiar with the new LibGDX 0.98.
I'm not quite sure, how to use a Drawable in the Scene2d package. My current code for
using a ".png"  as a Background for various classes looks like this:

```
new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("data/splitpane.png")));
```

Is there any easyer way to use a ".png" as Drawable than with these 3 classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the [API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/TextureRegionDrawable.html) we can see that there aren't more options to draw an image as you want.

libGDX makes things a lot easier, but you have to think that in the background of this library there are lots of OpenGL complex logic that cannot be simplified more than these functions actually do.

Here I leave a [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) to the wiki of libGDX where they explain with examples some of the functions in `Scene2d` package. Maybe this could be useful.

Comment: @Siggy1000 you could always write to the developers in their forum, they are pretty active and always answer ;), maybe you can give them some new ideas!

Comment: Concerning this, I got pretty bad experiences, but it is worth a try ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
new Image(new Texture(...)).getDrawable();
```